# How to Select a Specific Point on a Vuetify <v-slider> with Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, cypress

I'm testing how my app reacts to a user clicking on a specific spot on a basic [Vuetify `<v-slider>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders).  What is the best way to simulate this in a Cypress integration test?

For example, I can click on the middle of the `<v-slider>` with:

```
cy.get(#sliderID).find('input[role="slider"]').click()
```

However, i would like to click on a different spot of the `<v-slider>`.  For instance, for a `<v-slider>` with a `min` value of `0` and a `max` value of `100`, I would like to simulate a click on `25`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cypress accepts coordinates for click events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click.html#Coordinates)

You should be able to calculate the exact spot you'd like to click on by using the width of the element and the properties of the slider component (steps, max value and min value)

Comment: how to make it works?, could you provide the example, thanks

Answer (score 3):

GMaiolo's answer is fundamentally correct.

In case it should be helpful to anyone else, here is a quick function I made (based on GMaiolo's answer) to click on a specific point of a Vuetify `v-slider`:

```
// example usage: clickVSlider('#selectID input[role="slider"]', 0.25)

const clickVSlider = (sliderSelector, percentFromLeft) => {
  const sliderWidth = Cypress.$(sliderSelector).width()
  const sliderHeight = Cypress.$(sliderSelector).height()
  const pixelsFromLeft = percentFromLeft * sliderWidth
  const pixelsFromTop = 0.5 * sliderHeight
  cy.get(sliderSelector).click(pixelsFromLeft, pixelsFromTop)
}
```

Or, perhaps it is preferable to use a more 'composable function' style:

```
// example usage: cy.get('#selectID input[role="slider"]').then(clickVSlider(0.25))

const clickVSlider = percentFromLeft => subject => {
  const sliderWidth = subject.width()
  const sliderHeight = subject.height()
  const pixelsFromLeft = percentFromLeft * sliderWidth
  const pixelsFromTop = 0.5 * sliderHeight
  cy.wrap(subject).click(pixelsFromLeft, pixelsFromTop)
}
```

Alternatively, we can create a [Cypress custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html), although we want to make sure we [don't get too overzealous in the usage of custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Best-Practices):

```
// cypress/support/commands.js
// example usage: cy.get('#selectID input[role="slider"]').clickVSlider(0.25)

Cypress.Commands.add('clickVSlider', {prevSubject: true}, (subject, percentFromLeft) => {
  const sliderWidth = subject.width()
  const sliderHeight = subject.height()
  const pixelsFromLeft = percentFromLeft * sliderWidth
  const pixelsFromTop = 0.5 * sliderHeight
  cy.wrap(subject).click(pixelsFromLeft, pixelsFromTop)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Cato Minors answer did not quite work for me. I think they might have changed how `<v-slider>` is rendered in the DOM.

I am working with `"vue": "^2.6.11"` and `"vuetify": "^2.6.10"`.

I used Cato Minors custom command. but had to access another clickable element, since the rendered `v-slider` html looks like this.

```
<div class="v-slider v-slider--horizontal theme--dark">
    <input value="137" id="input-150" disabled="disabled" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" data-cy="parent-child-space-slider">
    <div class="v-slider__track-container">...</div>
    <div role="slider" tabindex="0" aria-valuemin="40" aria-valuemax="300" aria-valuenow="137" aria-readonly="false" aria-orientation="horizontal" class="v-slider__thumb-container primary--text" style="left: 37.3077%;">...</div>
</div>
```

Only the parent `div` had a `width` and `height` that I could make use of.

So I modified the usage like this:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="parent-child-space-slider"]').parent().clickVSlider(0.50);
```